# What's this strange symbol above the CP in Pokemon Go?

Tags: pokemon-go

What does this symbol represent? Thanks

[image: strange symbol]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That symbol indicates the Pokemon is boosted by the [weather](https://niantic.helpshift.com/a/pokemon-go/?s=finding-evolving-hatching&f=weather-boosts&l=en&p=web).

There are various bonuses that take place when a Pokemon is boosted by the weather:

- When catching a Pokemon in the wild, their base IV threshold is 4/4/4, and you can catch them up to lv35 rather than lv30
- When catching the raid boss, the Pokemon will be lv25 rather than lv20
- Attacks that are affected by the weather receive a 20% damage boost

Comment: And from a literal sense, the symbol looks like a kite being flown in the wind.

Answer (score 0):

That symbol means it is boosted by weather. Because it is a kite, that means the weather is Windy, and that boosts Zekrom.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).